# Are there any Non GPL Open Source PGP libraries for .NET out there

Tags: .net, pgp, openpgp

I'm looking for a free, open source API for encrypting and decrypting PGP files. I'd like to use it in closed source products, as well as open source ones, so it would have to be a license other than the GPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) is a library that is very useful for doing encryption work.

Searching for Bouncycastle + PGP turns up this blog post, which looks very useful.  It's in Java, but the C# port is nearly identical to the Java code:
http://cephas.net/blog/2004/04/01/pgp-encryption-using-bouncy-castle/